# Where In clause in Sqlite On Strings returning size of ArrayList 0

Tags: android

**SQLITE METHOD**
Where I have the code to get the values from my database

```
public ArrayList<Food> getGuna(String guna) {
        ArrayList<Food> food = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
//        String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + FOOD_TABLE + " WHERE " + DOSHSHAMAN + " IN (" + dosh + ") and " + GUNA + " IN (" + guna + ") and " + RASA + " IN (" + rasa + ") and " + VIRYA + " IN (" + virya + ") and " + VIPAK + " IN (" + vipak + ") ";
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + FOOD_TABLE + " WHERE " + GUNA + " IN(" + "'" + guna + "'" + ")";
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(sql, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            Food obj = new Food();
            obj.setFoodname(cursor.getString(1));
            obj.setDoshshaman(cursor.getString(2));
            obj.setGuna(cursor.getString(3));
            obj.setRasa(cursor.getString(4));
            obj.setVirya(cursor.getString(5));
            obj.setVipak(cursor.getString(6));
            obj.setCategory(cursor.getString(7));
            food.add(obj);
        }

        return food;
    }
```

Calling Method returning ArrayList size() 0
  In this method I am calling the above method which is returning me the size of ArrayList 0

```
  ArrayList<Food> gun = databaseHandler.getGuna(guna);
    Toast.makeText(this, "size"+gun.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    for (Food s : gun) {
        Log.e("GFoodNAME", "asasd"+s.getFoodname());
        Log.e("GCategory", s.getCategory());

    }
```

Comment: No, I have many records containing similar data that's why I have used wherein clause

Comment: Can you post your createtable statement?